# Is there an property like android:actionBarSize in iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, height

I'm developing in Xamarin and I don't know how change the height of navigation bar.
For android is easier because you've got a clear property "ActionBarSize"

I've tried a lot of things. Create a comun NavigationPage with HeightRequest property does not work

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In iOS we could set a custom TitlView by using custom renderer .

```
 using Foundation;
 using UIKit;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using xxx.iOS;
 using CoreGraphics;
 using xxx;
 using ObjCRuntime;
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
 namespace xxx.iOS
 {
public class MyPageRenderer: PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        var page = Element as ContentPage;
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;
        double height = IsiphoneX();
        UIView backView = new UIView()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            Frame = new CGRect(0,20,UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, height),
        };
        UIButton backBtn = new UIButton() {
            Frame = new CGRect(20, height-44, 40, 44),
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18),
        } ;
        backBtn.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
        backBtn.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);
        backBtn.AddTarget(this,new Selector("GoBack"),UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
        UILabel titleLabel = new UILabel() {
            Frame=new CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width/2-75, 0,150, height),
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20),
            Text = page.Title,
            TextColor = UIColor.Black,
            Lines = 0,
        };
        UILabel line = new UILabel() {
            Frame = new CGRect(0, height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 0.5),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,
        };

        backView.AddSubview(backBtn);
        backView.AddSubview(titleLabel);
        backView.AddSubview(line);
        View.AddSubview(backView);
    }
     double IsiphoneX()
    {
        double height = 44; //set height as you want here !!!
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
        {
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().SafeAreaInsets.Bottom > 0.0)
            {
                height = 64;  //set height as you want here !!!
            }
        }
        return height;
    }
    [Export("GoBack")]
    void GoBack()
    {
        NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
    }
    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = false;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
This is to add view over my pages. And now I hid Xamarin pages.
How can I to get down my page?

Comment: What means of hid Xamarin pages ?

Comment: My new subView adds over the xml pages.
I've tried to change the frame in a shellRender too.
`(renderer as ShellSectionRenderer).NavigationBar.Frame = new CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, 250);`

[link example](https://ibb.co/7RNrNgb)

Comment: Add the code in PageRenderer instead of shellRender .